# Pointer comparison in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, pointer-arithmetic

If I allocated something like

```
 size_t n = ???;
 unsigned char* s = malloc(n);
```

will it be perfectly defined behaviour to compare pointers to locations `s + i` for `0 <= i < n` in the sense that `s + i < s + j` if and only if `i < j`? Probably it is, but one reads that pointer comparison is defined only in a contagious array, and to a beginner it is not clear if an allocated thing as above would count as an "array" since that term has also a formal meaning in C, and also one reads about virtual memory without fully yet digesting that, and starts to worry... So I thought to ask to make sure.

Comment: Yes, it's legal and does what you expect.

Comment: As long as `s` is not `NULL`, pointer compare is good over one more:  `0 <= i <= n`.  Just cannot access `s[n]`.

Comment: There at least *has been* systems where different arrays could end up in different memory segments. And then comparing between them using `<` would not be meaningful.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, sorry, no const... sorry, p is s...

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica about i = n; actually, can't there be a "nightmare" scenario (very unlikely on standard machines I would guess) where the allocation is precisely at the end of the possible pointer size, so that we have an overflow of s + n = 0? then you would get s > s + n...

Comment: @Sasha No.  Last byte(s) can not be part of an allocation nor any object.  The address after an object is always valid.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica ok, I opened a new question for this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249331/initial-or-terminal-malloc-buffer-possible

Answer (score 4):

From the C Standard (3. Terms, definitions, and symbols)

> 3.15
>
> 1 **object**  region of data storage in the execution environment, the
> contents of which can represent values
>
> 2 NOTE When referenced, an object may be interpreted as having a
> particular type; see 6.3.2.1.

and (7.22.3 Memory management functions)

> 1 The order and contiguity of storage allocated by successive calls to
> the aligned_alloc, calloc, malloc, and realloc functions is
> unspecified. The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is
> suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type
> of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to
> access such an object or an array of such objects in the space
> allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated).

also this quote will be useful here (6.2.5 Types)

> 20 Any number of derived types can be constructed from the object and
> function types, as follows:
>
> — An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of
> objects with a particular member object type, called the element type.
> The element type shall be complete whenever the array type is
> specified. Array types are characterized by their element type and by
> the number of elements in the array. An array type is said to be
> derived from its element type, and if its element type is T, the array
> type is sometimes called ‘‘array of T’’. The construction of an array
> type from an element type is called ‘‘array type derivation’’.

and at last *6.5.6 Additive operators)

> 8 When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted
> from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the
> pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array
> is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the
> original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the
> resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression.
> In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an
> array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N
> (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and
> i−n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if
> the expression P points to the last element of an array object, the
> expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object,
> and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array
> object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array
> object. If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements
> of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
> object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
> behavior is undefined. If the result points one past the last element
> of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary *
> operator that is evaluated.

Comment: The problem is that there is formally no array object in sight, based on the expression `const unsigned char* s = malloc(n);`. There is just a pointer to an object of no declared type.

Comment: @Lundin As written in the note "2 NOTE When referenced, an object may be interpreted as having a particular type; see 6.3.2.1."

Comment: That refers to lvalue access which first of all assumes that the object is actually accessed, which doesn't happen here. And even if it is, that in turn calls upon the rules in 6.5 for effective type which in turn are insufficient to describe how the compiler should act.

Comment: @Lundin As it is written an object is a region of data storage and can be interpreted as having a particular type. So accessing a region of data storage using a pointer of the type char  * the data stored in the region is interpreted as data of the type char.  And "An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type"

Comment: No, as it is written, I quote "**When referenced**, an object may...". Referenced means de-referenced. A lvalue access as defined in 6.3.2.1 refers to (among other things) accessing a certain memory location through a de-referenced pointer to a certain type. None of it applies here. And even if it did, the standard is still unclear.

Comment: @Lundin The word "referenced" here has nothing common with dereferencing a pointer. It is used in the general meaning. For example "the Standard referenced by you and so on...".

Comment: It explicitly means lvalue access (which does indeed have a broader meaning than pointer de-referencing but that doesn't matter here). Just read 6.3.2.1.

Comment: @Lundin It actually means how a region of memory is interpretated. For example it can have the incomplete type void if referenced by means of a pointer of the type void * or as an object of the type char if is referenced by a pointer of the type char *.

Comment: So _now_ referenced suddenly means access through a pointer? Your argumentation is turning inconsistent. Well, it does mean that - _referenced type_ is a formal term in C.

Comment: @Lundin The descripton of the term object has nothing common with the referemnced type. It means only how a region of memory can be interpreted as an object.

Comment: ...during lvalue access. Again, no access is taking place here.

Comment: @Lundin If you reffer to a region of memory through a pointer of the type char  * then it means that you interprete the region as an object of the type char.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard has its problem here. Because what's returned from malloc is just a chunk of memory with no declared type. In theory it is not an array or any other type (yet). In practice the compiler must treat it like an array or otherwise the whole C language falls apart. Nobody thought of this when the C99 standard was designed and ISO C working groups since then have shied away from fixing the problem.

To tell if something is a valid access, we need to know its type, or if there is no declared type like in the `malloc` case, then at least we need to know the *effective type*, which is a system that the C standard launched with C99 to address such scenarios.

Formally, `s` points at memory location having no declared type. C17 6.5 §6 then says:

> For all other accesses to an object having no declared type, the effective type of the object is simply the type of the lvalue used for the access.

But you don't access it, so it has no effective type either. And since it has neither a declared nor an effective type, it cannot be an array of some type either. Doing pointer arithmetic on `s` which is not an array, is undefined behavior per C17 6.5.6 §8. Unless you access it first and thereby mark it as some sort of effective type.

Obviously we can't read the C standard literally here - it is broken. Specifically, it has the following defects:

- 6.5 §6 does not address how to treat "aggregate types" (arrays, structs) nor how to treat type qualifiers (const, volatile), in regards of effective type.
- 6.5.6 §8 does not support  pointer arithmetic on items with no effective type.

In order to produce some sort of meaningful executable, compilers therefore ignore all of this and treat whatever is returned by `malloc` as an array. Similarly, compilers tend to support pointer arithmetic on areas with no declared type just fine, or hardware-related programming in C would also be impossible.

So to summarize:

- Will it be perfectly defined behavior to do pointer arithmetic within this allocated chunk?
  No.
- Can you compare two pointers pointing into the chunk?
  Yes, you can always compare two pointers in C no matter where they point. But how will you get the pointers pointing into this chunk with no type, without using pointer arithmetic?
- Will it work just fine on every half-decent compiler ever released?
  Yes.

Comment: Maybe it's in there, but I'm having trouble finding where this addresses the question posed, which is about comparisons of pointers into the same allocated object.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Formally, you can do _comparisons_ with the relational operator, but you can't do _pointer arithmetic_ to locate the parts of the supposed array used for comparison.

Comment: "whatever is returned by malloc as an array" --> Hmmm, what is returned from `malloc()` is a pointer, not an array.  Suggest re-wording.

Comment: @Lundin, you *can* do pointer arithmetic with `char` pointers in cases such as this.  At least, that's how I read C23 6.3.2.3/7.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica No it is correctly written. The compiler _must_ be able to assume that the object is an array (or struct) even though it has no effective type. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to do `for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++) s[i] = something;` (where `s[i]` equals `*(s+i)` and 6.5.6 additive operators apply) to initialize the segment returned by malloc. Which in turn would break the whole C language and render it useless. If we just go by the rules of effective type, then `*(s+i)` would be pointer arithmetic on something which is not an array.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well yes, but that's another broken part of the language. Suppose I first iterate through the whole malloc segment using char pointers/char lvalue access for whatever purpose. Then later I access it through the type I actually intended to use there, like an `int*` to an `int` array... bam, strict aliasing violation. That is, `int* iptr = malloc(n); unsigned char* cptr = (unsigned char*)iptr; for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++) {cptr[i]=0;} ptr[0] = 1; // strict aliasing violation`. Surely this is not the intention but this is what the broken rules of effective type say.

Comment: We've already had this debate many times of SO. The consensus is always: effective type is broken, strict aliasing is broken. And in addition, the rules of pointer arithmetic are too strict to make C useful for a lot of applications, such as programming computers built with hardware (rather than built on theoretical fluff). You cannot write the most basic things like CRT, bootloaders, flash drivers etc in C without using pointer arithmetic on memory locations with no declared/effective type.

Comment: @Lundin With `void *malloc(...)`, the value returned from `malloc()` is a _pointer_, not the object.  The object this answer refers to is what is refence-able by a pointer.  This distinction is important for learners.