# Is memory allocated by malloc an array - same as allocated by calloc?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

The language of the C standard is sometimes not very clear and consistent.

1. Is object allocated by malloc an array. Common sense says YES, but the standard uses different wording for `calloc` and `malloc`

- `calloc` : *"The calloc function allocates space for an **`array`** of nmemb objects, each of whose size
  is size."*
- `malloc`: *"The malloc function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size"*

Generally an *array* is an *object* too.

I am looking for precise answers - not general common sense deliberations and real-life usages.

Comment: Seems very much related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77243945/pointer-comparison-in-c. Is that what triggered this question? My answer there covers this question too. TL;DR it is formally not an array but it must be treated like an array or the whole C language dissolves into nothing.

Comment: @Lundin, I've posted a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70185038/does-idiomatic-initialization-of-a-dynamic-array-invoke-undefined-behavior) some time ago. Taking standard literally will make pretty much every piece of C code in the world undefined.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, both functions return memory for objects with *allocated storage duration*.  This is first mentioned in section 6.2.4p1 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Storage Duration of Objects:

> An object has a storage duration that determines its lifetime. There are four storage
> durations: *static*, *thread*, *automatic*, and *allocated*. Allocated storage is described in
> 7.22.3.

And further in section 7.22.3, where it mentions both array and non-array objects:

> The order and contiguity of storage allocated by successive calls to
> the *aligned_alloc*, *calloc*, *malloc*, and *realloc* functions is
> unspecified. **The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is
> suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type
> of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to
> access such an object or an array of such objects in the space
> allocated** (until the space is explicitly deallocated). The lifetime of
> an allocated object extends from the allocation until the
> deallocation. Each such allocation shall yield a pointer to an object
> disjoint from any other object. The pointer returned points to the
> start (lowest byte address) of the allocated space. If the space
> cannot be allocated, a null pointer is returned. If the size of the
> space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined:
> either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size
> were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be
> used to access an object.

It should also be noted that such memory returned by these functions does not have an *effective type* until such time when it is written , which essentially means you can store whatever you want in such memory.  This is spelled out in section 6.5p6:

> The effective type of an object for an access to its stored value is
> the declared type of the object, if any. <sup>87)</sup> If a value is stored into
> an object having no declared type through an lvalue having a type that
> is not a character type, then the type of the lvalue becomes the
> effective type of the object for that access and for subsequent
> accesses that do not modify the stored value. If a value is copied
> into an object having no declared type using memcpy or memmove, or is
> copied as an array of character type, then the effective type of the
> modified object for that access and for subsequent accesses that do
> not modify the value is the effective type of the object from which
> the value is copied, if it has one. For all other accesses to an
> object having no declared type, the effective type of the object is
> simply the type of the lvalue used for the access.
>
> 87 ) Allocated objects have no declared type

Comment: I think that real problem is if pointer arithmetic is allowed before the object's effective type is set. Is `int *p = malloc(1000); p[10] = 42;` actually defined.