# initial or terminal malloc buffer possible?

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, malloc, undefined-behavior

Suppose I do something as follows:

```
size_t length = 1000;
char* p = malloc(length);
```

and then I want to loop over the elements, so most basic would be:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
  p[i] = ...; // or p[length - 1 - i] = ...
}
```

but also possible is

```
char* q = p;
for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
  *q = ...;
  ++q;
}
```

or in reverse

```
char* q = p + (length - 1);
for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
  *q = ...;
  --q;
}
```

**My question is**, what if I want to avoid the `i` and do something as follows:

```
char* const final = p + (length - 1);
for (char* q = p; q <= final; ++q) {
  *q = ...;
}
```

or in reverse:

```
char* const final = p + (length - 1);
for (char* q = final; q >= p; --q) {
  *q = ...;
}
```

It seems that there is a very tiny chance of erroneous behavior in those loops avoiding `i`; for the first loop, what if `p + length == 0`, i.e. we have a system where we were allocated memory just at the very end of the possible `size_t` limit and overflow happened... For the second loop, what if `p == 0`, i.e. we have a system where we were allocated memory just at the beginning of memory... In both these scenarios the loop will not end when needed...

Probably those do not really happen, but if this is undefined behavior then maybe it is better to loop with the `i` although it looks slightly less elegant..

---

Edit: Following Fe2O3's comment, I recalled that indeed I wanted to ask it a bit differently. Namely, I would like not an array of `char`s, but an array of elements of some struct type, so the struct is potentially relatively big, of size `3000`, say. Then it is enough for `p` to be  `< 3000` in order for the second loop to fail, it is not necessary for it to be `0`. Also, it is enough for `final` to be at the maximum size minus `3000`... Of course, `3000` can be even bigger...

Comment: `0` is, in most implementations, equivalent to `(void*)0`, or `NULL`. That's the "special indication" that allocation failed. So it cannot be used to simultaneously indicate a successful allocation. At the other end, the 'heap' boundary cannot _bleed into_ the `stack` that is located at the most high addresses. In other words, this is not a concern...

Comment: `p + length` is always correct according to the Standard. For the 2nd situation use `do ... while(q-- > p);`

Comment: Actually, your 4th snippet goes into UB... Better `for (char* q = final +1; q-- > p; )`... It is UB to decrement `q` to a value less than `p`, and then compare the two pointers...

Comment: @Fe2O3 thank you. But, please look at my edit. I refined the question to what I actually had in my head first.

Comment: On a 64-bit system, you would need 18 gazillion bytes of RAM to reach the end of `size_t`. Wouldn't worry about that! :-)  On smaller systems, surely the allocator can leave a single byte at the end, to avoid the overflow.

Comment: @pmg Thanks! The second suggestion is in fact excellent, didn't think about that for some reason. Regarding the standard, good to know, seems it also solves the first "problem" then...

Comment: @BoP I understand, but... What if I write such good software that it will still be used when the aliens come with that superior gazillion-RAM.... :)

Comment: `p + length` is always correct as a pointer (eg for pointer comparisons) ... not correct if you dereference it: `*(p + length)` is invalid!

Comment: @pmg I guess I am not sure what "correct" means... If it is 0 it is still "correct" by some understanding of the word... You mean it is assured to be non-zero, i.e. so that the comparison `p+length > p` is guaranteed to evaluate to true? Oh, ok, I see you edited your comment...

Comment: See [C11 6.5.6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6) point 8: "If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow"

Comment: @pmg Thanks! For reference: "...If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow..."

Comment: OT: If you write good software, it will be picked-up and rewritten so many times in so many ways that you won't recognise it... It's bad software that no-one wants to touch that lives on, and on, and on...

Comment: @Fe2O3 nice point of view, thanks.

Comment: @Sasha - It's good to consider how you write your software, but just don't over-do it.  :-)  For example, if you haven't actually tested your code on any machine where `0` is not `NULL`, it will likely fail on something else, like `short` being 23 bits. Portable code will not be portable exactly *everywhere*.

Comment: I can't find such a platform where heap is last in memory and memory goes all the way to the top of address space.

Comment: @BoP: It's a real shame that the Committee was not willing to recognize a set of traits that were common to most but not all C implementations, and then standardize the concept of "C but... [e.g. with 23-bit `short`]" dialects.  Such an attitude might have been perceived as "discriminating" against machines with 23-bit shorts, but would have made the language more useful--not only on machines with 16-bit shorts *but even on machines with 23-bit shorts*.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: The incrementing pointer version is ok, but the decrementing one is undefined.

The C standard defines pointer arithmetic in an array to be valid as long as the resulting pointer points at an element of the arrar or it points to "one past the end".  In that special case you get a valid pointer that can't be dereferenced (it is undefined to do so), but that will always compare as greater than any pointer to any element of the array

> **6.5.6.8** When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the
> result has the type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of
> an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from
> the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original
> array elements equals the integer expression. In other words, if the expression P points to
> the i-th element of an array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and
> (P)-N (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and i−n-th elements of
> the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if the expression P points to the last
> element of an array object, the expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the
> array object, and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array object,
> the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array object. If both the pointer
> operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
> element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
> behavior is undefined. If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it
> shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated.

So when you're incrementing the pointer, when you get past the end of the array, you'll get this special "one past the end" pointer that will compare as greater than the pointer to the last element and the loop will terminate.  With the decrementing loop, however, after the first element is reached, you'l decrement the pointer again and "underflow" giving undefined behavior.

Comment: This is almost true, except OP's forward version is using `p + (length - 1)` for `final` which is UB in case `length == 0`.

Comment: Thanks, except that @pmg above gave a solution also for the decrementing loop; write do ... while(q-- > p). However, that solution is problematic if length == 0, so should check for that separately, I guess...

Comment: @cafce25 right.. So I guess for both cases, increment and decrement, better to check for length == 0 first...

Comment: @Sasha, no you can make the condition `q < final` and initialize with `final = p + length;` Also FeO3 provides a version that works for the backward case without explicitly checking `length != 0`, even for different types than `char`

Comment: @Sasha When thinking about things, it's good to have a picture in your mind. Q: What is, for instance, a standard egg carton that holds 0 eggs? A: "air"... If you have an array, then you have at least 1 element.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize what people said (thanks!), the following should always work (I think):

```
size_t length = ...;
type_t* p = malloc(length * sizeof(type_t));
type_t* const q = p + length;

/* looping incrementally */
for (type_t* r = p; r < q; ++r) {
  *r = ...;
}

/* looping decrementally */
for (type_t* r = q; r > p;) {
  *--r = ...;
}
```

Comment: For the 3rd one, you need `for (type_t* r = q; r > p; ) { *--r=`... to be strictly correct.  Otherwise you'll incorrectly decrement the pointer even when `r == p` which is undefined.

Comment: @ChrisDodd If I understand correctly, I will decrement it, but the loop will end, so that I will not care about the value at `r` any more...

Comment: for the decremental one ... make sure `length >= 1` (*why would it ever be `0`? lol*) and stick with `do ... while` loop :-)

Comment: @Sasha: Re “I will decrement it, but the loop will end”: No, you cannot be sure that you will decrement it, based only on the C standard. You attempt to decrement it with `r-- > p`, but what does `r--` do? When `r` is already `p`, so that `r--` would make `r` point to before `p`, the C standard says the behavior is not defined. So you do not know that `r--` will decrement `r`. It could abort the program. Or the compiler could make deductions based on the fact that `r--` is only defined if `r` remains in the proper range and optimize your program weirdly based on those deductions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OK, thank you all, I appreciate it. I didn't realize that merely making the pointer "out of domain" should not be done. So if I understood correctly now, the code `char* p = malloc(10); --p; ++p;` is UB, can't be counted on as being the same as `char* p = malloc(10);`. But `char* p = malloc(10); p += 10; p -= 10;` is the same as the second...