# C: NULL > NULL always false?

Tags: c, pointers, standards, null-pointer

Is it guaranteed by the C standard that, given `type_t* x = NULL; type_t* y = NULL;` we always have `x > y` evaluating as false? I ask because of the conversation in [initial or terminal malloc buffer possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249331/initial-or-terminal-malloc-buffer-possible) from which it seems that one should be careful with pointer comparison, and only compare when one is dealing with pointers to elements of the same array, loosely speaking. However, it is convenient to have `x > y` evaluating as false guaranteed, because I want a struct which is an stack-ish array having fields for the first and post-last elements, and if this array still has `0` elements, it is convenient to set these fields to be `NULL`, and it is convenient to still allow for `for` looping over elements of the array, without checking explicitly whether the array has `0` elements or more, so such a comparison is handy...

Comment: You should consider whether you _really_ want to ask whether or not `NULL > NULL` as an expression is guaranteed to evaluate to `false` or whether you want to ask whether `X > Y` where both `X` and `Y` are null pointer values (of the same type) is guaranteed to evaluate to `false`. These are quite different questions. (In particular, `NULL` is _not_ a _null pointer value_ in general, but a _null pointer constant_ instead.)

Comment: @user17732522 yes, sorry, I mean the latter, edited accordingly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surprisingly, in C it appears to cause undefined behavior. Only `==` and `!=` can work with null pointers. The workaround is to cast the pointers to `uintptr_t` and compare the results.

[C17 6.5.8 Relational operators /5](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf)

> When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the address space
> of the objects pointed to. If two pointers to object types both point to the same object, or both point
> one past the last element of the same array object, they compare equal. If the objects pointed to
> are members of the same aggregate object, pointers to structure members declared later compare
> greater than pointers to members declared earlier in the structure, and pointers to array elements
> with larger subscript values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower
> subscript values. All pointers to members of the same union object compare equal. If the expression
> P points to an element of an array object and the expression Q points to the last element of the same
> array object, the pointer expression Q+1 compares greater than P. **In all other cases, the behavior is
> undefined.**

<sup>(bold mine)</sup>

This is unlike C++, where there's a clause explicitly saying that `<`,`<=`,`>`,`>=` are consistent with `==`,`!=`:

[`[expr#rel]/5`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#rel-5)

> If two operands `p` and `q` compare equal ([expr.eq]), `p<=q` and `p>=q` both yield `true` and `p<q` and `p>q` both yield `false`. ...

Comment: It is implementation-defined though whether `NULL` is a pointer type. It can be integral and then `false` is guaranteed. And in C++, as well as presumably C23, it may also fail to compile, if `NULL` is of type `nullptr_t`.

Comment: @user17732522 Mhm, but nobody's going to compare `NULL`s directly. OP most likely means that they have pointer variables they assign `NULL` to.

Comment: Yes, the question unfortunately is being imprecise about what it wants to ask.

Comment: @user17732522 is undefined not implementation defined.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes sorry, I edited the question accordingly, I mean variables assigned `NULL` to.

Comment: @0___________ No, implementation-defined means that the implementation should make a choice and document it (and there is only a limited set of permissible choice). The behavior of directly comparing `NULL > NULL` would, according to this answer, only be undefined if the implementation made the implementation-defined choice to use `(void*)0` (or similar) as definition of `NULL`.

Comment: @0___________  I am not sure what the C standard says about the relation of undefined behavior and implementation-defined behavior, but at least in the C++ standard implementation-defined behavior is clearly specified as parametrization of a set of abstract machines, while undefined behavior is a property of specific instances of this abstract machine parametrization (with a given input).

Comment: @user17732522 How C++ is related to the question?

Comment: @0___________ It is not, except for this answer mentioning it and me being more familiar with it.